# show google map on my site just as it show in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to show google map on my site through address or latitude and longitude Just as google map show.

Check the below image it show marker with title beside.
[image]

```
var myLatLng = {lat: 59.3488727, lng: 18.0432932};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 20,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'My title'
        });
```

I used the above code and when it show map on my site it look like this image.
Where i m doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to recreate a simple Google Maps experience in your website, I would recommend using the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) which includes a basic label alongside markers.

Otherwise, you might want to look at something like the [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/docs/reference.html) library which you can use to manually attach a text label to a marker using the full JavaScript API.